# Get data by Id using AJAX | JSON ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

i have this web service methode

```
List<object[]> List1 = new List<object[]>();
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public List<object[]> GetData(int ID)
        {
            var team = db.TEST.WHERE(a => a.id == ID).ToList();
            List1.Add(new object[]
                            {
                                team
                            });
            return teamList;
        }
```

and this my Function using Javascript & jQuer & Json

```
function BindList(id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/WebService1.asmx/GetData",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/Json; Charset= Utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    var list = "";
                    $.each(data.d[0][0], function (index, item) {
                        list += "<li class='text-secondary p-1'><a class='btn-link text-secondary'><b>" + item.Id+ "</b>" + ", " + "<span class='font-italic'><small>" + item.Name + "</small></span><small><a href='#' Onclick='Delete(" + item.Name + ")'> <i class='float-right far fa-trash-alt'></i></a></small></a>" + "</li>";
                    });
                    $("#list").html(list);// and this to print data to this list id 
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        }
```

and this my button to get data

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" onclick="BindMembersList(1)" value="button" />
```

My problem is where i need to put the id for give just data have id equal 1
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this url:

```
url: "/WebService1.asmx/GetData?id="+id
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an url you are calling, pass it on the url of your AJAX call like so:

```
function BindList(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/WebService1.asmx/GetData/" + id,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/Json; Charset= Utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                var list = "";
                $.each(data.d[0][0], function (index, item) {
                    list += "<li class='text-secondary p-1'><a class='btn-link text-secondary'><b>" + item.Id+ "</b>" + ", " + "<span class='font-italic'><small>" + item.Name + "</small></span><small><a href='#' Onclick='Delete(" + item.Name + ")'> <i class='float-right far fa-trash-alt'></i></a></small></a>" + "</li>";
                });
                $("#list").html(list);// and this to print data to this list id 
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

If it's not working or you need to pass more parameter to the action, you can specify them and using the "&" as separator like so:

```
url: "/WebService1.asmx/GetData?id=" + id + "&parameter2=" + param,
```

Anyway, your c# method is wrong since you are returning teamList, which is not implemented inside the action